# How to add event listeners to elements that are dynamically generated in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically generating HTML code and it works fine and I am sure that it contains the ID's that I am using.

However, I wrote some event listeners for these 2 dynamically generated ID's.

```
$("#dynamicID2").click(functionX);
$("#dynamicID3").click(functionX);
```

However, It doesn't work. Why is this? and how do I fix this?

Comment: One way would be `$(document).on('click', htmlclass, function(){})` but you have to use classes instead of ids.

Comment: @Lixus, classes aren't required to delegate events.  This would work just fine:  `$(document).on('click', '#dynamicID2', function(){})`

Comment: What about adding an event to `dynamicID3` without writing another `on('click')` function or without doing this `'#dynamicID2, #dynamicID3'`?